# generating correlated random variables of different distributions via gaussian copula

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I want to generate two random variables, one is normally distributed N ~N(10, 25) and the other one, E, is exponentially distributed with mean 1. I was not given a particular correlation coefficient.

First I get two independent standard normals A, B.

Then I generate a correlated normal C, with unknown correlation coefficient p through a linear combination of A, B,  $C = pA + \sqrt{1-p^2}B$.

To get N, I simply transform A such as $N = 10 + 5A$.

Then I use the normal CDF to get the $unif(0,1)$ variable corresponding with $C$, $F(C) = U$ where $U~unif(0,1)$. From inverse transform of exponential cdf,

I get that E = -ln(1-U).

Is this a correct approach? I am also not sure if given the information in the first two lines I could have inferred some correlation coefficient p.

Comment: if this is correct as is please lmk. else please answer where i went wrong

Answer (score 1):

It is the correct approach to generate the desired marginal distributions.

Taking $N = 10+ 5A$ and $E = -\ln(1 - F(B))$ we get independent random variables where $N$ has the normal distribution (mean $10$, variance $25$) and $E$ has the exponential distribution (mean $1$).

The Gaussian copula is applied by using $E = -\ln(1 - F(C))$ where $C = \rho A + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}B$. For a given ***specified*** $\rho \neq 0$, dependence is introduced.  The random variables $N$ and $E$ will have non-zero correlation but it is affected by other moments. We will not have $corr(N,E) =\rho$ precisely, but, rather a close approximation

$$corr(N,E) = \frac{\mathcal{E}[ \,(N - \mathcal{E}(n))(E - \mathcal{E}(E)) \, ]}{\sqrt{var(N)} \sqrt{var(E)}} \approx \rho$$

Comment: Um To generate E i used - ln(1-N(C)) if by N u mean the normal cdf.

Comment: I switched to your notation $F$ for the cumulative normal distribution function

Comment: .. and I'm not sure if you want correlation or not, but this is what happens if you put a  nonzero value to $\rho$

Comment: and also C = $\sqrt{\rho} A + \sqrt{1-\rho}B$ works as well as what i've said above. I'm not sure how you got $\rho$ and $\sqrt{1-\rho}$ for your C

Comment: That's a typo - sorry

Comment: I think i understand everything up to what you were saying that they are affected by other movements, can you explain? And also, in the last sentence do you mean that based on the information given, we can get an approximate $\rho$? i guess if the comments section is too long you can edit your answer lol

Comment: The Gaussian copula is a way to create random variables with known marginal distributions (perhaps non-normal) and force a dependence using a joint normal distribution.  In this case with two variables we use a bivariate normal distribution (where the dependence is controlled by a single parameter -- the correlation).  There are other copulas with more parameters, but this one is the easiest.

Comment: Now I would suggest that you generate a sample for $N$ and $E$ for some specified correlation, say $\rho = 0.5$.  Then calculate the correlation of $N$ and $E$, making sure you have a big enough sample so that the estimate of correlation settles down.  It will not converge exactly to $\rho$ ( the correlation of $A$ and $C$) but it should come close.  It ends up depending largely on $\rho$ but also on the means and variances of the marginal distributions in a complicated way.

Comment: Ok.. so the correlation of the Normals generated is not necessarily equal to the correlation of the desired exponential random variables..right? So if I were to generate, say 2 exponential random variables via gaussian copula with a given correlation $\rho_e$, I would need to figure out the correlation $\rho_n$for the normals first. how can i do that analytically? or is it done via simulation?

Comment: Your observation is correct.  It may  not  be possible to find $\rho_n$ analytically to achieve a desired $\rho_e$.  You could do it by trial and error with simulations.  On the other hand -- is it really necessary?  The point of a copula is to introduce dependence with specified marginals and the precise value of the Pearson correlation coefficient may not be so important.  The importance of this specific measure diminishes as we move away from joint normality.